# No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.MyStyle'

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

I'm new to android programming (developing on Android Studio 0.8.11) and I'm having issues applying a custom theme to an ActionBar.
My goal is to create a complete custom actionBar with different colours and resources. My min SDK is 16.
Here is the example theme definition in the /res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

I'm trying to applying this to all the app with the following line in the manifest xml:

```
<application> [...] android:theme="@android:style/Theme.MyStyle">
</application>
```

However when I try to lookout for "Theme.MyStyle" the auto-completion seems not to find it. In fact that part is reded out and the compiler says "No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.MyStyle'"  .

I'm just trying to figure out how to correct applying a theme, all the guides found even on android developer makes the theming easy but I can't find what's wrong!
Any tips? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@android:style** is for predefined android styles

Change this

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.MyStyle"
```

into

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStyle"
```